# Database suggestion for large unstructured datasets to integrate with elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-elasticsearch, aws-documentdb

A scenario where we have millions of records saved in database, currently I was using dynamodb for saving metadata(and also do write, update and delete operations on objects), S3 for storing files(eg: files can be images, where its associated metadata is stored in dynamoDb)  and elasticsearch for indexing and searching. But due to dynamodb limit of 400kb for a row(a single object), it was not sufficient for data to be saved. I thought about saving for an object in different versions in dynamodb itself, but it would be too complicated.
So I was thinking for replacement of dynamodb with some better storage:

1. AWS DocumentDb
2. S3 for saving metadata also, along with object files

So which one is better option among both in your opinion and why, which is also cost effective. (Also easy to sync with elasticsearch, but this ES syncing is not much issue as somehow it is possible for both)
If you have any other better suggestions than these two you can also tell me those.

Comment: How do you use this data, is it frequent queries or only occasionally?

Comment: I need to perform update and delete operations on data in database and also ingest data into it on regular basis. A single object size can reach upto 1-2 GB in future.

Comment: Also, for fast retrieval(searching) of this data into mili seconds I use elasticsearch currently, where I also do aggregation and geo spatial data queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at DocumentDB over Amazon S3 based on your use case for the following reasons:

- Pricing of storing the data would be `$0.023` for standard and `$0.0125` for infrequent access per GB per month (whereas Document DB is `$0.10`per GB-month), depending on your size this could add up greatly. If you use `IA` be aware that your costs for retrieval could add up greatly.
- Whilst you would not directly get the data down you would use either Athena or S3 Select to filter. Depending on the data size being queried it would take from a few seconds to possibly minutes (not the milliseconds you requested).

For unstructured data storage in S3 and the querying technologies around it are more targeted at a data lake used for analysis. Whereas DocumentDB is more driven for performance within live applications (it is a MongoDB compatible data store after all).

Comment: Thanks for answering my query. I need to clear further doubts on it. I only store data in DynamoDb currently, where I do write, update and delete operations on that data. And further sync this to Elasticsearch for performing fast search queries. So, basically I need database to do Write, Update, Delete operations via REST apis. Is S3 really slow(taking time in minutes) to do so? Also, if you can help me know the pricing of doing these operations in AWS DocumentDb for per gb per month(as the pricing above you listed is for S3 and couldn't find it for per GB / month for DocumentDb).

Comment: S3 is not slow by itself for an individual object, its when you query the data that it can take time. `$0.10 per GB-month` is DocumentDB. S3 is cheaper for this but if you use IA and frequently queried the data through Athena this might ad up in cost

Comment: If just writing then yes, it would be better :)